# Calling a script with bash -c option

Tags: linux, bash, shell

There are at least 3 possible ways of calling a bash script:

```
:~$./myscript
:~$bash ./myscript
:~$bash -c "./myscript"
```

One said that in the case #3 invocation (`-c` option) there is one more bash process in the hierarchy. I've prepared a simple test script:

```
echo "SHLVL: $SHLVL"  
ps aux | grep bash
```

The variable `SHLVL` is indeed greater by one in the #3 case, but the `ps` doesn't output any extra bash process in the #3 case. The only bash process connected to the script is

> ```
> bin/bash ./testscript
> ```

So where is this extra bash process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there seem to be an optimization in bash.

Lets make a `sleep20s` script:

```
#! /bin/bash
sleep 20
```

To avoid ambiguities, lets start a ksh shell.

With this command: `bash -c "./sleep20s"`, you get:

```
ksh
  sleep20s
    sleep
```

Ooops, where is bash? But know if we do something that requires the bash interpreter, such as calling the same command twice: `bash -c "./sleep20s;./sleep20s"`, then you get:

```
ksh
  bash
    sleep20s
      sleep
```

And bash is back. So bash could be clever and use an `exec` to start the child script in the trivial cases.

Comment: "So bash could be clever and use an exec to start the child script" - You mean just replacing bash code with scrip code as `exec` does?

Comment: @mulligan exacty